# Does irony support fuzzy completion?

Tags: completion, irony-mode, fuzzy-matching

I have set up company-irony backend for C/C++ auto-completion, everything works fine except that it doesn't support fuzzy match. I know ycmd has such feature, I am wondering whether irony can have similar support ?

Comment: Try `counsel-irony`, it can be configured for fuzzy completion.